# Why my Visual studio 2017 license will expire if I am already logged in?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I downloaded the free VS Community 2017 on my PC and today I get this message from VS saying that my license will expire today.

Whats happening? I signed in but the message still appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried signing out and in into your Microsoft account recently?

Comment: Yes, I did this